# How to close ioredis (nodejs module) when connected to a cluster?

Tags: node.js, redis, event-loop, ioredis

I've written a module that uses ioredis and some tests to go along with it.

The problem is, that when I it when ioredis is connected in cluster mode, mocha hangs after finish, even though I call `redis.disconnect()`.

It seems that something is still bound to the event loop.

Here is my test:

```
it('connects to redis cluster mode', async () => {
  //redisClientFactroy is my module
  let redisClientFactory = redisClientFactoryInit({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 7000
  })
  // it returns a redis.cluster instance if it recognizes it
  // 'redis' here is a cluster client
  let redis = await redisClientFactory.createClient()
  await redis.set('took123', 1);
  let took = await redis.get('took123')
  expect(took).to.eql('1')
  let nodes = redis.nodes()
  await Promise.all(nodes.map((node) => {
    node.disconnect()
    console.log("node disconnected")
  }))
  redis.disconnect()

  //tests are marked as done and passing, but mocha does not exit
})
```

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to use promises or close node connections by hands. Just call

```
redis.disconnect()
```

In cluster mode it will close all open connection themself. Look at [disconnect method in sources](https://github.com/luin/ioredis/blob/master/lib/cluster/index.ts).

If you still need to close in by hands, do not uses promises — disconnect do not return them. Just

```
nodes.map((node) => node.disconnect())
```

Comment: If you'll run the code in my question, you will see that despite using `redis.disconnect()`, mocha hangs after the tests finish. It may really close the connections as you say, but *something* stays in the event loop, preventing mocha from terminating

Comment: You do not need to use promises or close node connections by hands. Remove await Promise.all from your code: node.disconnect() do not using promises (#1) and you do not return promise in map code. It`s wrong by nature.

Comment: I added the part of the code with the promises as an extra attempt to close when I noticed mocha didn't terminate at the end. The issue has nothing to do with the promises part. Please run the code with mocha and see for yourself

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, and it fixed by call `redis.disconnect()`, every client should be disconnected.